# Node.js - Migrate htaccess.php file contents

Tags: node.js, .htaccess

I am migrating a site from PHP to Node.js. In this PHP site, I have a .htaccess file. That file looks like this:

**htaccess.php**

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.* 
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

I'm not sure how to migrate these settings to my Node.js app. My app is built with [Feathers.js](http://feathersjs.com/). Which, is built on top of Express. Still, I'm not sure how to get these cache settings into my app. When my app starts, I'm running the following, which is fairly boilerplate Feathers.js code:

```
app.use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  .use(favicon( path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico') ))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(routes)    
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(socketio())
  .configure(services)
  .configure(middleware)
```

Yet, I'm not sure how to integrate the expiration settings from the htaccess.php file into my Node.js app. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question well, You would require something like this.

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {

  if (req.url.indexOf("/images/") === 0 || req.url.indexOf("/stylesheets/") === 0) {
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=2592000");
    res.setHeader("Expires", new Date(Date.now() + 2592000000).toUTCString());
  }
  next();
});
```

You can also check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-expiry